# how to do a substring in qlikview?

Tags: qlikview

Currently , I have a field which brings in date from the database in this format: Fri, Jun 12 09:21:46 CDT 2017.
I am new to qlikview. How can I do a substring or subfield so I can get Jun 12 2017. Even better if I can get in this format: 12-Jun-2017. 
I would really appreciate the help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is the [subfield](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/November2017/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/StringFunctions/SubField.htm) function or you can use the [mid](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/November2017/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/StringFunctions/Mid.htm) function.

I'd recommend getting it out as a date so you can mess with the format wherever you want. That would look something like this:

```
=date(date#(
    subfield(YourDateString,' ',6) & '/' &
    subfield(YourDateString,' ',2) & '/' &
    subfield(YourDateString,' ',3),
    'YYYY/MMM/DD'
))
```

That picks the year, month and date from the string using `subfield` and then turns it into a usable string which is fed into the `date#` function (which reads strings and converts to numbers) and then finally into the `date` function (which makes nice human-readable dates from numbers)

or this:

```
=date(date#(
    mid(YourDateString,6,6) & ' ' & 
    right(YourDateString,4),
    'MMM DD YYYY'
))
```

Similar to the one before, that gets the month and day, using `mid`, first, adds on the year, using `right`, and then does the same with `date#` and `date`

Both should work in script or charts and both are, of course, dependent on your having a consistently-formatted string to work reliably...

Answer (score 0):

If the data item is numeric then try:

Date(DATDOC,'DD/MM/YYYY') as Date

Or else:
Date#(DATADOC,’DD/MM/YYYY’) as Date

Answer (score 0):

Since this is already on a date format, you can just use the function Date() on your load script.

```
LOAD
Date(Your_Date, 'DD-MMM-YYYY');
```

Same goes for your expression.